# SSAS Semi-Additive measures across subset of dimensions

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, cubes

I have a simple fact table with four dimensions and two measures.
Dimensions: Location, Date, Drug, Drug route

Measures: Count of drugs dispensed; Count of patients as each location for the date

The granularity of the data is rolled up to the month level.  Every combination of Location, Date, Drug and Route has the Drug Count and Patient Count pre-aggregated.  Records with the same Location and Date will also have the same Patient Count.

The dispensed drugs are fully additive, but I only want the patient days to SUM over locations and dates.  However, I can't figure out how to make the semi-additive options work across the 2 drug-related dimensions.

Is this beyond the Business Intelligence package?  What would be my next approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be solved with a "Distinct Count" aggregation.

I would go back to the SQL view on the fact table, and add a calculated column to concatenate Patient Id, Location Id and date.  Then in the SSAS cube definition, I would set the "Count of patients" measure to use the "Distinct Count" Aggregate Function, based on that "patient+location+date" column.

Comment: I edited the original question when I saw your response.  It seems to me that I need a function that sums a measure field over a distinct set of facts.  Kind of like a "Distinct Sum" function.  Historically, I have tried the Distinct count of a concatentation of fields, but I found that when I filtered by patient characteristics, my calculation of location patient counts were also affected.  Patients with no drugs also need to be included in my patient count.

Comment: If you want a patient count independent of some dimensions, I would create a SQL view on the fact table that grouped by patient, location and date, then feed that into the SSAS cube as a new Measure Group.  You can just use a Count aggregation.  Personally I would add this as "Count of Patients by Location" and keep the "Count of Patients" measure as described above - both are useful for different analyses.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough!  This has been haunting me for over a year!